# How can Google Tag Manager fire correct pixels on the conversion page based on landing page UTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, tracking-pixel

I am managing a crowdfunding website. We place ads for individual campaigns using different content networks like Adgebra and Taboola.

Whenever someone clicks on an ad on any of these content networks, he/she lands on the campaigns page with corresponding UTM parameters in the url. From this page, he/she can choose to make the payment, follow along 2 more pages to finally land on the **thank you** page.

We have placed pixels through GTM on the thank you page for Adgebra as well as Taboola. Now, we have not written any specific logic to fire individual  pixels. Ideally, if the UTM was of Taboola, the Taboola pixel should be fired and same for Adgebra.

Here is what I don't understand - the UTM parameters are getting propagated from the campaign page to the thank you page, so how does GTM determine which pixel to fire. If there is no conditional logic, then both pixels should be fired on each open of the thank you page, but that's not the case.

Here's the Adgebra pixel

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  var p1="751";
  var adgebraElement_TransactionId = document.getElementById('adgebra- 
transaction-id');
  var orderId = adgebraElement_TransactionId? 
adgebraElement_TransactionId.value : 'no adgebra element present';
  var p2="[" + orderId + "]";
  var p3="[product_Id]";
  var adgebraElement = document.getElementById('adgebra-cart-value');
  var cartvalue = adgebraElement? adgebraElement.value : 'no adgebra 
element present';
  var p4="[" + cartvalue + "]";
  var p5="[flag~custom_values]";
      var adgConvScrpt=document.createElement("script");document.body.appendChild(adgConvScrpt);adgConvScrpt.async=true;var adgConvParam="p1="+p1+"&p2="+p2+"&p3="+p3+"&p4="+p4+"&p5="+p5;adgConvScrpt.id="adg_conversion_pixel";adgConvScrpt.src="https://adgebra.co.in/Tracker/Conversion.js?"+adgConvParam;</script>
```

Comment: Google Analytics stores the UTM data in the users GA session that is associated with their cookie.   I don't think that tag manager has access to that data though.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller then how does GA attribute the source and medium for the conversion event?

Comment: GA stores the UTM info in the GA database linked to the session id of the user.   Only the session id is stored in the cookie.   Unless you have access to the GA database you can't get the UTM info.   I don't think GTM has this access.    It is possible to store the UTM info in your own cookie if you need it for other purposes.   I have no idea how easy or hard it would be to do so with GTM.

Answer (score 1):

This is very interesting question. As a campaign manager our Duty is to add only pixels to GTM on pages. But we get different numbers according the advertisement provider. Here logic is simple.

1. All the pixel are fired on each condition (i.e. thank you page). GTM
   doesn't know from which ad source the user is coming ?
2. Its the advertising partners duty or logic that defines the user
   identity.
3. Here  for eg. Adgebra adds their query string and Taboola do the
   same for their ads.
4. All the adverting partners get all the hits data.
5. They then checks and count the hit / conversion to their account if the user / page has any info from their ad only (i.e their query string identification / cookies value).

Hope this is clear now for you . if You are Familiar with Google ads after setting up their conversion we can see Tracking Status as "Recording conversions" even is the ad is not running. So that means Google is successfully tracking conversion actual number will changes if the person is form Google ad network.